# Вложенный import в python

Tags: python, модули, python-import

Прошу прощения за возможную очевидность, недавно серьезно изучаю Питон.
В целом разобрался с `import`, но остался наивный вопрос.

Есть главный модуль `main`, он импортирует `numpy` и пару вспомогательных:

```
import numpy
import func_1
import func_2
```

Но дело в том, что в `func_1`, `func_2` также требуется `numpy`.

По наивности я думал, что достаточно импортировать `numpy` в главном модуле *до импорта дочерних*, и он туда как-бы подтянется. Понятно, я ошибался, и теперь импорт прописан в каждом модуле.
Но нельзя ли все же это сделать как-то экономнее?

Comment: А зачем? . . . .

Comment: Что означает "экономнее"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допустим, что это работало бы как вы предположили выше. А теперь представим себе, что вы пишите другую программу, где вы **не** используете *numpy*, но используете модуль *func_1*. Вы делаете импорт *func_1* в главном модуле, запускаете *main*, и получаете ругань на непонимание что такое *numpy*. "Но постойте! Какой *numpy*? В главном модуле никакой *numpy* не используется, зачем я должен его импортировать?" - подумаете вы. И окажетесь правы. Вот почему всё необходимое для модуля должно импортироваться в самом модуле. Чтобы модуль был самодостаточен.